What is the best way to wait GIO objects updated in GTK application?
I wait socket updation with IOChannel of GLib because g_io_add_watch function of IOChannel adds the GIOChannel into the default main loop context. This is so nice I do not need to make an additional thread to wait for IO, just one main loop handles both UI events and IO events.
Turning to the GIO objects, for example GSocket, GIOChannel only supports file descripter, not supports GSoket. So my question's are as follows:

What is the best way to wait GIO objects updated in GTK application?
Is there a way to use GSoket with IOChannel?
If not, are there nice way to wait IO events of GIO objects without making additional thread separated from GUI main loop?


You can get the underlying file descriptor of the socket, check https://docs.gtk.org/gio/method.Socket.get_fd.html

In the callback function of the g_io_add_watch(), the socket is passed as a parameter. Inside this function, which way is better to use this socket as is, or to use the newly created GSocket from this socket?
